# HowTo merge two VertX RowSets

Tags: vert.x

I have two RowSets from different Databases.

```
RowSet<Row> db1Rows;
RowSet<Row> db2Rows;
```

Is it possible to merge, sort them and return the merged RowSet?

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting them to JsonObjects - and then merge the two